# looping through two sets of data in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, loops, if-statement, nested

I have two sets of data, one for radar, one for lidar. The files are in csv, and i have added the data to empty lists called radar and lidar. The data is 600x600. Each row of data is in a list. so 600 values per row (and therefore per list).
The radar file tells me where the islands of land are in the sea, so any values >150 will be land
The lidar will tell me the height of the land.
so first i used this code:

```
for i in range(len(radar)):
    for j in range(len(radar[i])):
        if radar [i][j] > 150:
            radar [i][j] = 'land'
        else:
            radar [i][j] = 'sea'
```

i now need to get the height values of all the areas classified as land (or land over >100) but dont know how to check simultaneously for land and then find its value. Any ideas?

Comment: so `radar[i][j]` initially contains height values?

Comment: no radar checks the TYPE of object present (sea or land). If the value in the data is over 150, the pixel it represents can be classified as land, and if below 150 the pixel will be sea.

Comment: so what's the meaning of that numeric value (>150) ? what does it represent ?

Comment: Dont know. The booklet just says values over 150 will be land. Maybe something to do with colours or something. Thats just a guess (numbers range from 0 to 255)

Comment: ah, I missed this line `The lidar will tell me the height of the land`. so `lidar[i][j]` contains height values, but what will you do with height values ? should you assign them somewhere ?

Comment: so once ive determined which areas are land. Those areas that are land i need to pull out their heights from the lidar file. After that i need to use the data to calculate the mass of the land. I can do that part, but dont know how to pull the lidar data out of specific part of the radar file

Comment: Are you familiar with pandas (https://pandas.pydata.org/)? It is a great library for working with dataframes

Comment: @York77 Do they appear the same? Both Radar and Lidar are of the same arrangement?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming radar and lidar are of the same orientation (same size and same access), then you can use the same `i` and `j` to access `lidar[i][j]` once you determine radar is something you need, to get the corresponding lidar measurement for that pixel.  So below I made a results list were I add a tuple of `(i, j, height)` for all cases of land.

```py
results = []

for i in range(len(radar)):
    for j in range(len(radar[i])):
        if radar[i][j] > 150:
            radar[i][j] = 'land'
            results.append((i, j, lidar[i][j]))
        else:
            radar [i][j] = 'sea'
```

You could then calculate based on that results, or you could copy a matrix of land, or however you want to do the calculations after that, but you should be able to access the height like above which is what you main question was.

Comment: This then gives: TypeError: append() takes exactly one argument (3 given)

Comment: Did you remove the double parenthesis? `(( ))`

Comment: My bad. Theres always some tiny detail you forget when writing code. Thanks bud.

Comment: No issues, if that solves your question hit the check mark next to my answer, if not let me know.